# The Open Set $X-\lbrace x \rbrace$

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification

I am task with proving the following:
if $x \in X$ then $X- \lbrace x \rbrace $ is an open set

I kind of have an idea but I am unsure about it and how to express it.

I was thinking about using the Hausdorff property i.e. $\forall y \neq x \in X$    $\exists U_y  $ where $U_y$ is open and where $y\in U_y$ but $x\notin U_y$ and then take the union of these sets $U_y$

Comment: Hint: is the set $\{x\}$ closed in $X$?

Comment: @Matthew what is X?

Comment: Based on the tags, I'm pretty sure you mean $X$ to be a metric space, but Hausdorff is enough.  Your proof idea sounds fine.  The property you gave is not quite the same as Hausdorff, though.  It's weaker ( so, still true for Hausdorff spaces )  Closer to something called $T_1$.

Comment: You have already proved it. Your construction shows it.

Comment: You actually proved that in $T_1$-spaces singletons are closed. The converse is also true.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y\in X-\lbrace x\rbrace$. Then $y\neq x$ and thus there is an open $U_{y}$ such that $y\in U_{y}$ and $x\notin U_{y}$. Thus $U_y\subset  X-\lbrace x\rbrace $. Thus it's open because it contains an open neighbour for every element.

Comment: Is it appropriate to substitute open neighbour with open ball?

Comment: @Matthew if you are in a metric space,yes. However if you are in metric spaces you don't need Hausdorff property,because metric spaces are Hausdorff and it's much easier to imagine thinks in metric spaces.